# Setting up a server with an older distro

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have a client who's had an e-commerce website up for years and now wants parts of it updated. As far as I can tell, throughout the years whenever they've had minor updates, they just updated the live site. My updates are a little more intensive so I want to setup a dev version of the site. The site is using really old technology and I need to get the exact (or close enough) versions of the software they are using.

Technologies and versions:

- CentOS 4.7
- PHP 4.3.9
- Apache 2.0.x
- MySQL 4.1.22

I need to get this setup on a test server so they can view the changes online. I have some Linux knowledge but I have no idea how to get older versions of distros setup on a VPS for instance. Could anyone recommend the easiest way of getting a "clone" of the live server up on a VPS somewhere? I was thinking of spinning up an AMI but I can't find one with CentOS 4.7.

Comment: PHP 4's final release was five years ago. Time to bite the bullet and do an update to the site.

Answer (score 2):

NO. CentOS 4.x went end-of-life in February 2012. Not to mention the security issues inherent to running an unsupported public-facing Linux distribution.

The client should consider making a move to the current OS and using this test environment to make sure everything is okay with the new versions of the critical technologies.

Where is the existing site being hosted? Is it on a physical server? Building a VM with a [close version of CentOS 4](http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/4.1/isos/x86_64/) is certainly possible. The .ISO files are still out there.

Comment: Understood, I definitely am aware of the security implications, I plan to restrict access and only have the machine running when showing updates. The client understands they are using an outdated OS, just wants to get this out the door. Current site is hosted on some shared host I believe. Are there any VPS companies that allow you to use your own distro ISO fairly easily?

Comment: Hmm... If I were in your situation, I'd spin up a local virtual machine on a workstation or server just to model the client's environment. Any CentOS 4.7-4.9 would be okay.

Comment: I have an extra machine in my home. Would I be able to point a URL at my home server? Would that depend on my ISP?

Comment: @dod yes, a lot of it hinges on your ISP and firewall setup.